# Get a Team from a Name column via lookup on multiple CSV files

Tags: csv, powershell-2.0, lookup, export-to-csv

Ok I have been coordinating the work of two ladies in order to get a complete csv I will want to import into our AD .

**Master spreadsheet**

```
$csvMasterData | Select-Object Name, Username, Mail, Business, Team, Role, Phone, Mobile
```

Here my "Team" column is empty

**Other spreadsheets that do have the Team against the Name**

```
$anneCSVFiles = "Anne-1.csv","Anne-2.csv","Anne-3.csv", "Anne-4.csv" ,"Anne-5.csv"
$nameAndTeamCsvData = $null


#extract the name and team from each of the files ( which were essentially tabs on    another spreadsheet)
$anneCSVFiles | %{
    $nameAndTeamCsvData += Import-csv $_ |  Select-Object Name, Team 
}
```

Ok so far good - I have tested both by writing to file

Now I want to *recreate $csvMasterData* but this time I want do a dynamic lookup through Name 
on $nameAndTeamCsvData so that I can populate the **Team** value for each **Name** col per a row.
I got as far as this intermediate step which I was hoping to use as a function or pipeline

```
  $team = $nameAndTeamCsvData | Select-Object Team If (Name -Contains "Dan The Man" )
```

But then I get a bit stuck .. Can someone put me out of my mystery  and suggest how I can get my dynamic lookup to work

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Got in this morning. Post coffee and pre coffee. If there is a slicker way of writing this then please comment. I am still getting my head around how deal with each object in a pipeline process..... AD Import here I come!!!!

```
# get the master csv file into a list of objects
$csvMasterData = Import-CSV -path $masterCSVFile

now update the empty team value for user object
$csvMasterData | ForEach-Object {

$masterName = $_.Name 

# looup the Name to see if we can get the team
$userObject = $nameAndTeamCsvData | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $masterName }

# replace the mastercsv.Team with the one we have looked up
$_.Team = $userObject.Team
```

}

Comment: actually there is a bug here.. the $_.Name  referenced twice is meant to be in the context of either the mastercsv or the one I am trying to lookup so. In fact it is just the mastercsv .. So I am comparing apples with apples and not apples with oranges. ... Any advice